# C++11 equivalent of Haskell's "inits"

Tags: haskell, c++11, functional-programming

Just a short question:

Is there any C++11 equivalent of Haskell's [inits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v%3ainits)?

> The inits function returns all initial segments of the argument,
>   shortest first.

I'd like to do sth. like

```
reverse $ inits [1..10]
```

C++11 supports *[std::reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)*, but i could not find sth. like *std::inits*.

The List will be represented in C++ as a *std::vector*.

Comment: Nope there is not. You could achieve it with a loop and shrinking

Comment: Well... That's exactly what I didn't want to do :-)

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't want to do that. The C++ standard library is very slim and usually doesn't contain functions that can't be implemented efficiently. TBH I wonder why Haskell has it, it's gotta be for convenience only (and symmetry with tails, which is actually efficient)

Comment: I'm programming my current project in C++11. I'm *still* trying to figure out what is actually possible in C++11 and which opportunities and alternative idioms the language offers.

Comment: You should look at the functions in <algorithm> then. They are pretty much all there is algorithmically apart from the specific data structures and other stuff like I/O, regex, threading etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it working purely functional:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  vector<int> nums = { 1,5,5,9,8,7,6 };

  auto inits = accumulate(nums.begin()+1, nums.end(), // Iterate between second and last element
                  vector< vector<int> >{ vector<int>{nums.front()}}, // Initialize accumulator
                  [] (vector< vector<int> > &acc, int j) { // Lambda constructing further elements
                        auto tmp = acc.back();
                        tmp.push_back(j);
                        acc.push_back( tmp );
                  });
  return 0;
}
```

Inits will be a vector of vectors of int's.

Everything without (visible) loops :-)

Comment: Well, the pending question is: What is more elegant in C++11? Using a simple loop or std::accumulate...

Answer (score 1):

For a random-access range (since you mention `std::vector`), a range of successive slices is manageable. This will also work with forward and bidirectional ranges, although that will incur an additional linear cost when computing the distance. With Boost.Range:

```
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/sliced.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

namespace R = boost::adaptors;

template<typename Range>
using range_difference_t = typename boost::range_difference<Range>::type;

namespace functors {

template<typename Range>
struct slice {
    using difference_type = range_difference_t<Range>;
    Range* range;

    explicit slice(Range& range)
        : range(&range)
    {}

    boost::sliced_range<Range> operator()(difference_type index) const
    {
        return R::slice(*range, static_cast<difference_type>(0), index);
    }
};

} // functors

template<typename Range>
using inits_type =
    boost::transformed_range<
        functors::slice<Range>,
        const boost::integer_range<range_difference_t<Range>>
    >;

// calling inits with rvalues is not supported on purpose
template<typename Range>
inits_type<Range> inits(Range& range)
{
    using diff_t = range_difference_t<Range>;
    return R::transform(
        // use boost::size instead of distance to restrict
        // inits to working efficiently on random-access ranges only
        boost::irange(static_cast<diff_t>(0), boost::distance(range) + static_cast<diff_t>(1)),
        functors::slice<Range> { range }
        );
}
```

[Demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35f3194be2aa7475).

This solution benefits greatly from C++14, leaving us with just:

```
// same includes

template<typename Range>
auto inits(Range& range)
{
    namespace R = boost::adaptors;
    using diff_t = typename boost::range_difference<Range>::type;
    return R::transform(
        boost::irange(static_cast<diff_t>(0), boost::distance(range) + static_cast<diff_t>(1)),
        [range = &range](diff_t i) { return R::slice(*range, static_cast<diff_t>(0), i); }
        );
}
```

[C++14 demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cc48551fb9a4917).

As for a non-slicing solution (i.e. closer in spirit to the Haskell version), this would require writing iterators by hand, with ‘interesting’ lifetime considerations. I would not recommend it.